# HDMI to VGA convert

Tags: hdmi, vga

I just bought a new HP Pavilion dv7t Quad Edition laptop that has HDMI out. I already have a couple of monitors that are VGA and I'd like to hook up one of these to dual monitors.  I've read some sketchy reviews of products that try to convert directly from HDMI (digital) to  VGA (analog), so I was wondering if someone has a good recommendation on how to hook these two together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can hook up any VGA monitor to a HDMI port with such a cable:

[image]

Comment: I know that I can use a cable, but is it good enough or would I need a conversion box.  See product reviews at: http://www.amazon.com/HDMI-VGA-HD15-Male-Cable/product-reviews/B001OLCHJ6/ref=dp_db_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1

Comment: what about scaling?

Comment: this one says it all: "People seem to be buying this item expecting it to be VGA to HDMI, or bi-directional. This was made to send the video from your HDMI source, to your VGA display." of course such a cable does not convert a VGA signal to HDMI, but that is not what you want anyway. so don't worry, a VGA monitor works just fine on a HDMI output.

Comment: It looks like you might need something [like this](http://www.jakeludington.com/hdtv/20080423_convert_hdmi_to_vga_with_hdcp.html) because even if you are doing HDMI source -> to VGA monitor, you might still run into the "protection" decoding that the site referenced describes.  That cable runs about $130.

Comment: That 'cable' above needs to be more than just a cable. Somewhere in it is not just a bit of copper but an active conversion chip which understands the digital HDMI signal and outputs it via a DAC. That means it is not a "cable" at all, even though it looks like one,

Answer (score 3):

As you are confused how to fix up these two together the best way out is to use a
[VGA to HDMI](http://www.kvmstuff.com/video-routing/video-converters/hdmi-vga-converter.html) Converter